Deriving the non-central chi-square PDF from characteristic function
This SE question has a nice answer describing how to derive the PDF of the chi-square distribution by inverting its characteristic function, in an elegant method using contour integrals.
How can we use the same contour integral method to derive the PDF of the non-central chi-square distribution, from its characteristic function:
$$\phi(t)=\frac{\exp\left(\frac{i\lambda t}{1-2it}\right)}{(1-2it)^{k/2}}$$
It is known that the resulting PDF would be in terms of the modified Bessel function of the first kind. Wikipedia says that the Bessel function can be described as a Fourier transform of 'powers of quadratic functions', which might be the link.
